# Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'NavigateFunction'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

new to Typescript and react..I updated useHistory to useNavigate in react-router-dom v6.

In the useEffect hook `navigate.listen(e) => {`
returns the error Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'NavigateFunction' and I can not figure out why. Could someone help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For better questioning on Stackoverflow, please review [this doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This is how route changes can be captured in react-routerv6:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // triggered on route change
    console.log('new route: ', location)
  }, [location])
  ...
}
```

Docs: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation